# Laravel upload multifile get NULL inside controller

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to upload multi file with laravel4.

View:

```
{{ Form::open($address,array('route' => array('address.update', $address->id, 'files'=>true))) }}

{{ Form::file('images[]', ['multiple' => true]) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller:

after choose some file and try to send files into controller i get NULL inside controller. for example:

```
 public function postUpdate()
    {
        $files = Input::file('images');
        dd($files);
    }
```

`$files` in this phase is `NULL`, why?

Comment: try printing all data Input::All()  do you get anything?

Comment: @kamlesh.bar yes, that have images item into array, but `Input::file('images');` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `Form::open()` tag. Try something like.

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => array('address.update', $address->id),'files'=>true))}}
{{Form::file('images[]',array('multiple'=>'true')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```